# Docker cpu shares and garant minimum allocated CPU for container

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

I develop a application which runs in three containers on my development box with a quadcore with hyperthreading, meaning there are 8 cores to be used by the system and docker.

Thy CPU allocation for the containers is done by docker-compose as follows:

- redis: cpu_shares: 1024
- mysql: cpu_shares: 1024
- app:   cpu_shares: 4096

I am troubled by timing out requests to redis. The load is minimal, but the utilization of redis is in bursts with longer breaks, at least in the development environment.

Hence, I assume docker is not assigning enough CPU shares to the redis container. I thought allready to put a constant artificial load on redis to let docker assign more CPU shares to it.

Is there an other way of ensuring a certain CPU share for a container?

Answer (score 0):

With Docker for Mac your containers are all running in a HyperKit VM. The VM has an allocation of CPU and memory which is a subset of the total on your Mac.

You can change the allocation in [Preferences](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#/preferences) - by default the Docker VM has 2 CPUs and 2GB RAM.

Comment: if I have allocated 2 cpus to docker for mac, does it mean all my mac applications will only be able to use at most N - 2 cores even if my docker VM is idle?